# browser console showing message repeatdly `[Violation] 'message' handler took 220ms`

Tags: angular, handler, message

Getting this error `[Violation] 'message' handler took <N>ms` on angular application browser console continously while running in development mode using yarn.

On click it takes me to zone.js at line number 1755.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/re52G.png)

Not sure but this indiacate.